# Why does ByRef not work in conjunction with WithEvents?

Tags: vb6, byref

I think I have a fairly good idea what the difference is between `ByVal` and `ByRef` in VB, but my issue is when I try using it in conjunction with a member that is declared with `WithEvents`.

I have the following method:

```
Private Sub SafeCloseAndDeRefConnection(ByRef cnx As ADODB.Connection)
On Error GoTo ErrH
    If Not cnx Is Nothing Then
        If (cnx.State And adStateConnecting) = adStateConnecting Then
            cnx.Cancel
        End If

        If (cnx.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then
            cnx.Close
        End If

        Set cnx = Nothing
    End If
Exit Sub
ErrH:
 Set cnx = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I have a class member declared as such:

```
Private WithEvents Connection As ADODB.Connection
```

I then want to close the connection and then call it as such:

```
SafeCloseAndDeRefConnection Connection
```

But after the call to `SafeCloseAndDeRefConnection` the `Connection` variable is *not* set to `Nothing` and still has its original reference.

If I remove the `WithEvents` keyword the call to `SafeCloseAndDeRefConnection` works as expected (but obviously events can then not be handled)

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

P.S. I have found a similar [question elsewhere](http://computer-programming-forum.com/69-vb-&-database/4a3faf68e4960892.htm), but the workaround does not work in my scenario.

Comment: A `WithEvents` object cannot be passed `ByRef` and if you attempt it a "copy" is passed just as if you'd declared it `ByVal`.  It sort of has to be this way to manage connecting and disconnecting the actual object's outgoing event interface and the client's sink object.

Comment: Try implementing a "fluent" function which you can then use like this `Set Connection = SafeCloseAndDeRefConnection(Connection)`

Comment: @Bob77 Thank you for your reply. It makes a bit sense (as much as VB can make sense). Do you maybe have a reference where this is explained in more detail? VB6 is a "pre-Web 2.0" language, so help with this is somewhat scattered and not so easily found on the web.

Comment: The details of the mechanism is a Windows topic, and not a VB6 topic.  VB6 makes an effort to eliminate the need to understand such implementation details.  You might try "Events in COM and Connectable Objects" though at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694379(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps call:

```
Set Connection = Nothing
```

After `SafeCloseAndDeRefConnection(Connection)`

This will force the destruction of the object and not rely on VB6 to do it for you!

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose why the method exists in the first place.